# SQL trigger does not fire through asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, sql, triggers

Trigger does not fire. An asp.net app tries to insert a record, which should fire this trigger, but it fails to fire. Using Windows 2008R2, framework 4.5. Here is trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterInsert] ON [dbo].[AspNetUsers] 
with execute as owner
FOR INSERT
AS

declare @email nvarchar(128),
@ID nvarchar(128)

select @email = i.Email,
@ID = i.Id 
from inserted i;    

insert into LoginHistory
([Email],[LoginID])
Values 
(@email, @ID)

insert into AspNetUserRoles
(userID,RoleID)
select @ID, AspNetRoleID from ConfirmedRoles
where email = @email
```

Have run alter database TestDB set trustworthy on

Comment: If you manually try inserting a record into `AspNetUsers` through SQL Management Studio, is it successful?  I'm thinking this may be a SQL problem, rather than .NET.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `select @email = i.Email,
@ID = i.Id from inserted i;` - it's non-deterministic. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Thank you for replies...You're right onskee, it doesn't run through SQL Management Studio. The error is 'Cannot execute as the database principal as the principal 'dbo' does not exist. Any clues?

Comment: This fixed it: use [your_database] EXEC sp_changedbowner 'sa' The database had been restored from another server...had probs with 'owner' permissions.